# Sweave: How to get blank lines as in the source?

Tags: sweave

How can I get a blank line before the second comment in the PDF file of the following .Rnw file? I tried to work with `keep.source` and `strip.white`, but I still don't get the blank line -- all the chunks are "pasted" together.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<setup, eval=FALSE>>=
## some comment
a <- 1
b <- 2

## some comment (there is no newline before this comment...)
c <- 3
d <- 4
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you look at `knitr`? It is said to give more formatting choices.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know about any option for keeping the blank line. What you could do:

(1) If you need the named chunk kept together, you could simply put a # at the beginning of the supposedly blank line:

```
<<setup, eval=FALSE>>=
## some comment
a <- 1
b <- 2
#
## some comment (there is no newline before this comment...)
c <- 3
d <- 4
@
```

Less attractive, but you have at least something similar to a blank line, and keep your chunk.

(2) If you don't care for keeping the chunk together, you can separate it into two blocks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\begin{document}

<<setup, eval=FALSE>>=
## some comment 
a <- 1
b <- 2 
@

<<eval=FALSE>>=
## some comment (there is no newline before this comment...)
c <- 3
d <- 4
@
\end{document}
```

This gives you the appearance you like, at the price of losing the structure of your chunk.

Hope this helps,
Rainer

Comment: Solution 1 gives me: `ERROR: You can't use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode`.
Solution 2: does not work when you have a nested for loop with logical blocks (separated by newlines) inside -- you couldn't close the for loops.

Comment: (1) You have probably run pdflatex on the .Rnw file and forgot to Sweave it before - that is how I can reproduce this error. You get it for every line with a #, right?   --  Forget (2) anyway, it would have worked in the simplified sample but obviously not in a more complicated situation

Comment: I did a stupid mistake: I compiled the .Rnw that had the indented lines by four chars (to easily copy-and-paste to stackoverflow :-) ). It's working now, but the `#` are still ugly. I wonder if `fancyvrb` can solve that.

Comment: This is a Sweave  issue, not LaTeX. I don't think `fancyvrb` can help. You could, of course manually edit your .tex file before running pdflatex. Put something like `#*#` in the .Rnw where you want the blank line, and then replace it in the tex file. But that would need to insert, on one line each, `\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}` in order to create that one blank line, and this even without `>`